# Auto-indent after pressing `Enter` between tags

Tags: visual-studio, auto-indent

Please see the GIF below:

[image]

I am using **Visual Studio Code**. By pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I can make the auto indent in the next line.

So, I guess there is a more convenient way or package which can accomplish that by just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Hi @xianshenglu, the weird thing is that my VSCode is able to do that automatically after I hit enter now ( it works most of the time so far, but sometimes it doesn't work, I can't figure it out). My VSCode version is 1.25.0, you might want to update your VSCode first to see if that works for you.

Comment: As of 2018.10.4, I find vscode will accomplish that by just pressing `enter` when I am writing `html` like `div`. But it doesn't work with `style` or `script`. That is really weird.

Comment: did you find the solution of this issue? As i was facing the same issue and could not solve it, i moved to Atom.

Comment: It's funny I used Visual Studio 1998, and new line was always automatically indenting in C++. In 2022, it should stop working, and you have to type all your indentation manually. Good new world of magical fairies.

Comment: So no solution? I'm puzzled. None of the answers below actually help!

Answer (score 8):

In preference->editor search for autoIndent and make it full

[image]

Comment: I have that setting enabled yet cannot get the indenting to happen automatically.

Comment: Maybe the option `brackets` in `Preferences->Editor: Auto Indent` may work better for some as it will keep the line indentation and honor indents from within brackets.

Comment: Neither helps. Full, brackets nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem by switching Language Mode from Django HTML (for some reason it was auto detected) to HTML.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or directly press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> => Select HTML)
2. Print 'Change language mode' and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Select HTML

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still having this problem, but I stumbled across this other post that seems to have a solution:

[Visual Studio Code Auto close tag and indent XML as with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235400/visual-studio-code-auto-close-tag-and-indent-xml-as-with-html)

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

EDIT: I've just realised that this causes the language mode to be changed to HTML, which may lead to unexpected/unwanted behaviour. It suits my needs, however.

Comment: As of 2018.10.4, I find vscode will accomplish that by just pressing `enter` when I am writing `html` like `div`. But it doesn't work with `style` or `script`. That is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Emmet preferences, I'm not sure if it's a good solution, but it works.

- In the preferences, search `emmet.includeLanguages`
- Click `Edit in settings json`
- In the right column, click on `User settings`
- Add `"emmet.includeLanguages": {"php": "html"}` on the last line

Comment: It has nothing to do with `php`. And emmet support html by default.

Comment: True with HTML, but if you write HTML in a PHP file, it doesn't work without my modification

Comment: What about JavaScript and HTML? No indent after {. No indent after <>.